# PHP date() increase/decrease week store in $_SESSION

Tags: php, session, date, increment, descendant

The following code will increase/decrease week by 1:
(yes, my application requires the value to be stored in a `$_SESSION`.

```
if (isset($_POST['decrease'])) {
  $week_value = ($_SESSION['sess_week'] = $_SESSION['sess_week']-1);
}
else if (isset($_POST['increase'])) {
  $week_value = ($_SESSION['sess_week'] = $_SESSION['sess_week']+1);
}
else {
  $week_value = ($_SESSION['sess_week'] = date('W'));
}

echo $week_value;
```

However I would like it to reset at week 52 (new year). How can I do this? I'm new to programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (isset($_POST['decrease'])) {
  $week_value = $_SESSION['sess_week'] == 1 ? 52 : --$_SESSION['sess_week'];
}
else if (isset($_POST['increase'])) {
  $week_value = $_SESSION['sess_week'] == 52 ? 1 : ++$_SESSION['sess_week'];
}
else {
  $week_value = ($_SESSION['sess_week'] = date('W'));
}
```

Comment: Thank's everyone for the fast replies. I went with @xdazz code. It worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `date("W")` function to get the week number of the current time. If it is week 1, simply set it to 1 (or 0 if you start there).

You can play around and test it out by using a `mktime()` as a second parameter in the date function to verify the outputs.

```
<?php

    if (date("W")==1)
    {
        $week_value =1;
    }
    else
    {
        if (isset($_POST['decrease'])) {
          $week_value = ($_SESSION['sess_week'] = $_SESSION['sess_week']-1);
        }
        else if (isset($_POST['increase'])) {
          $week_value = ($_SESSION['sess_week'] = $_SESSION['sess_week']+1);
        }
        else {
          $week_value = ($_SESSION['sess_week'] = date('W'));
        }
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility to do this is as follows.
(I took it that you meant that if the week is more than 52 it shall be 1. Additionally I added
that if the week drops below 1 it shall be 52 again, thus the last week of the last year).

```
if (isset($_POST['decrease']))
{
     $week_value=$_SESSION['sess_week']-1;
}
else
{
     if (isset($_POST['increase']))
     {
          $week_value=$_SESSION['sess_week']+1;
     }
     else
     {
          $week_value=date('W');
     }
}

if ($week_value>52)
{
     $week_value=1;
}
else
{
     if ($week_value<1)
          $week_value=52;
}
$_SESSION['sess_week']=$week_value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do modulo (`%`) with 52.

That way you can assure that your week will always be less than 52.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
if( $week_value == 52 )$week_value = 0;
```

Comment: This might not work if the person hasn't logged in for a while.